How to remove first 3 characters of a visual-line block selection?
So I'm using a language where adding -- to the beginning of a line will comment the line.
To comment a block of code that I have selected using visual-line, I do this:
map <F2> <C-v>0<S-i>-- <Esc>

Now I want to be able to comment a block of code that I have selected using visual-line.
I tried this:
0<C-v>x

But this cuts everything from my original cursor position to the front of the line.
From visual-line block selection, how do I select (and delete) only the first letter (or first two letters) of those lines?

I would typically just use :s to delete the first 2 chars.  eg:
:s/^../

You can also do
:normal xx

or
:norm 2x

Note that all of these will get a range inserted, so although you may type :normal 2x, the display will be :'<,'>normal 2x

Recent versions of Vim (since v9.1.0375 released April 27th 2024) come with the builtin comment plugin.
It provides the gc command to toggle comments on a motion or visual selction.
The gcc command would do the same for a single line.
This will work for all known file types that set the 'commentstring' option (read: I'm not aware of a filetype where it wouldn't work).
Note that this solves the problem on a higher abstraction level.
We're not talking about inserting or erasing characters, we're now talking about comments.
And we're doing so in a language-agnostic way.
In case you prefer to use F2 over the default of gc, you can create a mapping.
The following minimal setup will enable it:
packadd comment
filetype plugin on
vmap <F2> gc 

(You will probably also want to create a mapping for normal mode)
You can find more information with :help comment-install, if that help section can't be found, it's likely because your Vim version is too old.
In that case, you could fall back to tpope's vim-commentary plugin which first established the gc command.
If your file type isn't supported, you can write a filetype plugin as described in :help write-filetype-plugin.
